# Adobe Flash video player

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm a Flash nostalgia guy and I'm looking for a Flash project or .fla file that encapsulate video player (with controls, seek bar etc)

I googled it a lot and couldn't find it. Can someone point me?

Comment: What about Video Player component normally found with other UI components in Flash/Animate IDE?

Comment: @Organis What version of SDK it is? I have CS4, is that available there?

Comment: It is not about **SDK**. Flash UI components is a palette of standard UI controls: checkbox, dropdown, textarea, radiobutton/group, videoplayer, etc. They are like custom components, that go with their own code and skins — but they are packed into your Flash IDE. You can find them somewhere like **Window** in the main menu then **Components**. Than you drag-n-drop the ones you need to the Library or directly to stage (this operation automatically puts all required skin elements to the Library).

Answer (score 0):

@Organis answered my question correctly.

In AS3 UI controls, there's all I needed.

In AS2 UI controls there's some funny player that throws error when exported, even if I run .flv files that it supports only.